# Logical Equality versus Object Reference Equality

Tags: java, string, equals, stringbuilder

I am studing for the OCA 8 certification. What does it mean "Logical Equality" in Java ?

I have this case:

```
String s1 = new String("java");
String s3 = new String("java");
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("java");
StringBuilder s4 = new StringBuilder("java");

if (s1 == s2)      {    System.out.print("1"); } //error
if (s1.equals(s2)) {    System.out.print("2"); } //false
if (s1.equals(s3)) {    System.out.print("3"); } //true
if (s2.equals(s4)) {    System.out.print("4"); } //false
```

The part :

The method `equals()` on object `String` is redefined to compare the value of the object with another one. For this reason when I excecute the row :

```
if (s1.equals(s3)) {    System.out.print("3"); }
```

I have the result 3.

On the object `StringBuilder` the method `equals()` is not redefined so it will compare the object reference equality. For this reason when I execute the row of code:

```
if (s2.equals(s4)) {    System.out.print("4"); }
```

I have the result `false`.

My question are:

- Why when I excecute `if(s1 == s2)`, I will get a compile error?
- Why when I excecute `s1.equals(s2)` it is false?

Comment: Have you looked at the compiler error for the first part? Which part of the error message did you not understand? For the second question, why would you expect a `StringBuilder` to be equal to a `String`?

Comment: i have read the compiler error (it says that they are 2 different object ).
For this reason i was asking about Logical Equality in java.

I wasn't excepted that the 2 object will be equal, but i was suposing the situation where i need to create 2 object's , defining the same methods ( where one looks for the value equality and the other look for reference equality )

Comment: If you weren't expecting that the two objects would be equal, I don't understand why you're asking the second question. I'm afraid your comment is generally unclear :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Why when i excecute if(s1 == s2) i will be a compile error ?

The `==` operator is a [reference equality operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3). Quoting the JLS:

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5).

In your case, the two operands are of type `String` and `StringBuilder`, which are not compatible: a `String` can't be cast to a `StringBuilder` and vice-versa.

> - Why when i excecute s1.equals(s2) it is false ?

`String` and `StringBuilder` are two different types. The `equals()` method in `String` checks whether the given argument is also of type `String`, which is not the case here, so an instance of `String` can never be equal to an instance of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: when i need to consider the case of equality or not with 2 different objects ?

Comment: @liriooliro What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why when i excecute if(s1 == s2) i will be a compile error ?
> 2. Why when i excecute s1.equals(s2) it is false ?

1. Yes. Because `String` isn't a `StringBuilder`. You'll get "incompatible operand types String and StringBuilder" (because `String` isn't a `StringBuilder`).
2. Again, because `String` isn't a `StringBuilder`. You could use `s1.equals(s2.toString())` (which would be `true`).

Answer (score 0):

I just discover the reason [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
1012    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
1013        if (this == anObject) {
1014            return true;
1015        }
1016        if (anObject instanceof String) {
1017            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
1018            int n = count;
1019            if (n == anotherString.count) {
1020                char v1[] = value;
1021                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
1022                int i = offset;
1023                int j = anotherString.offset;
1024                while (n-- != 0) {
1025                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
1026                        return false;
1027                }
1028                return true;
1029            }
1030        }
1031        return false;
1032    }
```

I was confusing from the reason that the equals method took an object like parameter ( and for this i was thinking that it was treated like an Object inside the method, but i see that it is the second if condition that work only for String object ( and in this i found the response of my question about Logical Equality ).
Thnk to all